# creating arrayList of arraylists

Tags: java, arraylist

I was trying to create an ArrayList of ArrayLits. Then, whenever I added an ArrayList to my initial ArrayList, I get My 2nd ArrayList in the initial ArrayList copied to the first ArrayList in the initial ArrayList. Here is my Code. Thank you for any help.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList> msebi = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
ArrayList<Pair> temp = new ArrayList<Pair>();
Stack<ArrayList> arrayListStack = new Stack<ArrayList>();
Pair pair = null;

for(int i=1;i<finalList.size()-1;i++){
    pair = finalList.get(i);
    if(finalList.get(i+1).getDepth() > finalList.get(i).getDepth()){
                temp.add(pair);
                if(i == finalList.size()-2){
                    temp.add(finalList.get(i+1));
                    msebi.add(temp);
                }
            else {
                temp.add(pair);
                msebi.add(temp);
                temp.clear();
            }
}
```

Kindly Note that I have created another Class that is Named Pair. This Pair consist of a String and depth, and thus we have getDepth(); Also, I have in the main class ArrayList finalList = new ArrayList();
Thus, Whenever I am trying to copy the content of the ArrayLists within the msebi ArrayList, I got the values of the second arraylist the same as the first one.

Comment: What exactly is your question? As written, it's pretty unclear.

Comment: why i starts from 1?

Comment: I have started from 1 since the initial element is the root. And I don't want to touch this root. Actually, here in this code is part of an implementation to an XML dress that i want to transform it into an ArrayList of pairs, where each pair represent the node name and its depth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add your `ArrayList` called `temp` to your outer `ArrayList` called `msebi`, `msebi` contains a reference to `temp`, not a copy.  Then you immediately `clear()` `temp` and build it up again.  You have multiple references to the same `temp` list in `msebi`.

Create a new `ArrayList` instead of clearing the old one.  This way, when a list is added, it's left alone, because you will be operating on another list object.